# how to derive character number from ascii table in assembler?

Tags: assembly, ascii, nasm

it is necessary to create an assembler program that will ask you to enter 1 character, then display the entered character and its code in the ascii table, for example, "You entered 9 | 57". Compiled NASM

Comment: The character is the character number.

Comment: The problem you actually need to solve is converting a 1-byte number to a string of decimal digits.  (Or just pass it to `printf("%c | %hhu\n", c, c);`)